# Draw a right angled edge from one side of a rectangle to the other

Tags: tikz-pgf

Basically I am trying to replicate the diagram below, using Tikz.

[image: RNN Cell]

I have gotten this far, with a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    shorten >=1pt,->,
    draw=black!50,
    node distance=2.5cm,
    %
    input/.style={draw=black, circle, fill=black!30, minimum size=1cm},
    cell/.style={draw=black, rectangle, rounded corners=3mm, minimum width=3cm,
                 minimum height=1.5cm, fill=black!10},
    %
    pre/.style={->, semithick},
    post/.style={<-, semithick}
    ]

    \node[cell]  (cell)   at (0,0)        {$R$};
    \node[input] (input)  [below of=cell] {$x_t$} edge[pre] (cell);
    \node[input] (output) [above of=cell] {$h_t$} edge[post] (cell);
    %
    \draw[pre, bend right=90, rounded corners=5pt] (cell.east) to (cell.west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: My own attempt]

What I cannot get to work is the right angled arrow from the right side of the rectangle to the left. Due to this I have not yet even attempted the "skip" in the arrow from A to h_t.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a code which provides the image you would like to achieve. You can play with the exact coordinates and the line width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    shorten >=1pt,
    draw=black!50,
    node distance=2.5cm,
    %
    input/.style={draw=black, circle, fill=black!30, minimum size=1cm},
    cell/.style={draw=black, rectangle, rounded corners=3mm, minimum width=3cm,
                 minimum height=1.5cm, fill=black!10},
    %
    pre/.style={->, semithick},
    post/.style={<-, semithick}
    ]

    \node[cell]  (cell)   at (0,0)        {$R$};
    \node[input] (input)  at (0,-3) {$x_t$} edge[pre] (cell);
    \node[input] (output) at (0,3) {$h_t$} edge[post] (cell);
    %
    \draw[rounded corners=5pt] (cell.east) -- (3,0) -- (3,2) -- (0.2,2);
    \draw[rounded corners=5pt,->] (-0.2,2) -- (-3,2) -- (-3,0) -- (cell.west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**:

This is somewhat closer to your original image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    shorten >=1pt,
    draw=black,
    node distance=2.5cm,line width=2pt,
    %
    input/.style={draw=black, circle, fill=black!30, minimum size=1cm},
    cell/.style={draw=black, rectangle, rounded corners=3mm, minimum width=3cm,
                 minimum height=1.5cm, fill=black!10},
    %
    pre/.style={->},
    post/.style={<-}
    ]

    \node[cell]  (cell)   at (0,0)        {$A$};
    \node[input,fill=cyan!40] (input)  at (0,-3) {$x_t$} edge[pre] (cell);
    \node[input,fill=violet!40,line width=2pt] (output) at (0,3) {$h_t$} edge[post] (cell);
    %
    \draw[rounded corners=5pt] (cell.east) -- (3,0) -- (3,2) -- (0.2,2);
    \draw[rounded corners=5pt,->] (-0.2,2) -- (-3,2) -- (-3,0) -- (cell.west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the "closer to actual photo" version, but as I said I am looking to keep the color scheme I initially had! Again, thank you.